# Fill JavaFX combobox by javascript class (Nashorn)

Tags: javafx, combobox, nashorn

I try to use my custom class which I have created in my script (the script is written in Nashorn) and after that I try to use this custom class to fill in as items in combobox. I know that if I want to see correct values in combobox that the class has to override method toString, but in this case I do not know much how can be overriden this method in my custom class written in Nahorn.
Below I provide my code where the variables cmbCategories is JavaFX combobox and CategoryItem which I try to use as object to fill in the items in combobox and display as category name.
I would appreciate any suggestion or ideas how can be this problem resolved.

```
var ClientBuilder = Java.type("javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder")
var Platform = Java.type("javafx.application.Platform")
var Executors = Java.type("java.util.concurrent.Executors")
var Response = Java.type("javax.ws.rs.core.Response")
var String = Java.type("java.lang.String")
var List = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList")

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(function () {
    print("Calling for category data...")
    var categoryData = ClientBuilder
        .newClient()
        .target(String.format("%s%s", "http://localhost:8080", "/client/action/categories"))
        .request()
        .get()

    if(categoryData.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        var categories = JSON.parse(categoryData.readEntity(String.class))
        var categoryItems = new List();

        for each (var category in categories) {
            categoryItems.add(new CategoryItem(category.id, category.category))
        }
         Platform.runLater(function() {
           cmbCategory.getItems().addAll(categoryItems);        
         }); 
    } else {
        print(categoryData.getEntity().toString());
    }
})



function CategoryItem(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;

    this.toString = function () {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ScriptEngine` to retrieve an appropriate string in the `cellValueFactory` of the `ComboBox`.

Simplified example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByMimeType("application/javascript");

    ComboBox<Object> comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.setCellFactory(c -> new ListCell<Object>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
                bindings.put("a", item);
                try {
                    // use script engine to retrieve text
                    setText(Objects.toString(engine.eval("a.name", bindings)));
                } catch (ScriptException ex) {
                    setText("Error");
                }
            }
        }

    });
    comboBox.setButtonCell(comboBox.getCellFactory().call(null));

    Bindings b = new SimpleBindings();
    b.put("cmbCategory", comboBox);
    engine.eval("function CategoryItem(id, name) {this.id = id;this.name = name;}\n"
            +"var Platform = Java.type(\"javafx.application.Platform\")\n"
            + "var categories = [new CategoryItem(1, 'a'), new CategoryItem(2, 'b'), new CategoryItem(3,'c')]\n"
            + "for each (var category in categories) {cmbCategory.getItems().add(category);}", b);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(comboBox));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I don't see the purpose of using JavaScript for this though. Everything you do in the javascript code could be done from java code more efficiently...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I forgot to mention that I have used WebFX browser where I try to use script which is downloaded with fxml from the server. Maybe I could use compiled classes which could be downloaded from the server as controller to current fxml file, but for this kind usage the javascript will be more efficient.